# Android Calculator subtraction

Tags: android, double, calculator

I am working on an android calculator. the user is pressing the buttons for 1 to 9 and decimal dot, and then inputnum (arraylist ) would then parse the display as input, and then oepration and then display the answer. The related codes as follows:

```
ArrayList<Double> inputnum = new ArrayList<Double>(); 
double inputnum1; 
double inputnum2;    

...


inputnum.add(Double.parseDouble(Fakedisplay.getText().toString()));        
case SUBTRACT: 
        inputnum1 = inputnum.get(0); 
        inputnum2 = inputnum.get(1); 
        inputnum.removeAll(inputnum); 
        inputnum.add(inputnum1 - inputnum2); 

        Fakedisplay.setText(String.format("%.19f", inputnum.get(0)));             

        String strf2=Fakedisplay.getText().toString(); 
        String strippedf2 = Double.valueOf(strf2).toString();  
        if (strippedf2.endsWith(".0")) 
            strippedf2 = strippedf2.substring(0, strippedf2.length() - 2); 
        Fakedisplay.setText(strippedf2);
```

Problem:
For 1000.84 - 1000.01 it will gives 0.830000000000041, which is not desired for the presentation, 
Yet this problem just only occur for subtraction, exactly the same codings for add, multiply and division but work very well, ie: 1000.84+ 1000.01 presenting 2000.85 and no more, 1000.84*1000.01=1000850.0084 and no more, 1000.84/1000.01 also works and present correctly.

Why is it so special for subtraction? how to handle it?

Comment: the problem is: how to present the exact answer of 0.83 instead of 0.83000000041. it is because it works well for +, x, / except subtraction. I would like to know why subtraction is so special and see if there are ways to tackle and make for better presentation as 0.83 sharply

Comment: thanks a lot for your prompt reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Decimal Format to Show long value upto N Decimal Digit.

```
DecimalFormat round = new DecimalFormat ("###.##");
String output = round.format(inputnum.get(0));
Fakedisplay.setText(output);
```

**Output = 0.83 for  0.830000000000041**

Comment: it works! sorry for such simple thing...haha...i am too new and learning for the codings~thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The math calculations are being performed via binary calculations. Not many numbers less than 1 can be represented exactly using binary which is why you are receiving your strange results - they are the best interpreted representation.

If you wish to avoid this problem, I would suggest using Decimal instead of Double (as decimal works with base 10 instead of base 2). Another alternative would be using Math.Round to get a more accurate calculation. Another suggestion again (but probably the least precise) would be to display the end result as a string and then truncate all values after the second decimal place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : http://www.hackpundit.com/android-tutorial-simple-calculator-app/

```
buttonSub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mValueOne = Float.parseFloat(edt1.getText() + "");
        mSubtract = true ;
        edt1.setText(null);
    }
});
```